# Can someone guide me in making my hw. Its about enum.

Tags: java, if-statement, random, enums

Create a program using enum for the following values.
3 objects
Name:
Age:
Status:
*if single, your program should print the random reason for being a single:
1. Waiting in vain
2. Taken for granted
3. Choosy

Comment: and what did you try so far?

Answer (score -1):

```
as far as I understand, the only candidate for enum is the status. 
public enum Status{

SINGLE,MARRIED,WIDOW ...
}


public class Person{
    String[] reasons = {"Waiting in vain","Taken for granted","Choosy"};
    Status status;
    int age;
    String name;
    Random random = new Random();

    public Person(Status status, int age, String name) {
        this.status = status;
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public printRandomValue() {
        if (status == Status.SINGLE) {
            int index = random.nextInt(reasons.length);
            System.out.println(reasons[index]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to do other people's homework here. (No, I didn't down vote, just a hint)